# Tag search results different from main window and truncated when adding tag to a question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, android-app

When searching for a tag while writing/editing a question, the results are:

1. different in ordering compared to searching it in the *in-app* site's "Tags" page (as opposed to "Questions"/"Users").
2. less than in the in-app site's "Tags" page, and scrolling down does not yield more results (only shows 15).

Comment: I couldn't repro (1), the tags are sorted by popularity by default, so if you're using other sort, then it'll be different compared to when writing question. For (2), I could repro on SE app v1.0.84... though it's already better than the browser version (only 6)

Comment: Typo: v1.0.83, not v1.0.84

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are by design.

1. Tags in the tag picker are shown by popularity.  This matches the default tag sort and the behavior on web.
2. The provided results are not supposed to be an exhaustive list of all matching tags but the best matches for what you've typed in so far.  On the web, only 6 tags are offered in the completion dialog.